# Docker-compose Kubernetes ENV properties interoperability

Tags: configuration, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I'm building my staging environment using **docker-compose**, with application that was previously ran in Google Cloud using **Kubernetes**.

My application was configured, using ENV properties provided inside **Kubernetes** container, and now after switching to **docker-composite**, I have different naming convention for linked services.

I can think of few solutions, for my problem:

1. Change my application, to support alternative configurations, so it would support both **docker-composite** & **Kubernetes**
2. Create aliases in **docker-compose** or **Kubernetes** so that configuration would always be available in single format in both environments, and I would not need to touch my application configurations.
3. Maybe some other way, which I don't see

I want to go with the 2nd solution, but I don't know how exactly to configure it. Have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the environment section to define 'docker-compose' variables like PARAM1=${PARAM2}. In this case, docker-compose will have the same variables that Kubernetes has.